# Port based routing in docker container

Tags: ssh, docker, iptables

I have a docker application container (`node:latest` image) which has two network interfaces:

- **eth1:** Which is a the default interface and is the bridge network between all containers from a service. (Managed by `pipework`, but I can't change anything in that level)
- **eth0:** Which is a regular `docker0` interface and has access to everywhere except those on `eth1`.

And here is the default routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.25.88.254    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.25.88.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

As you see it is necessary to have `eth1` as default interface, but it causes me a problem: My application needs `ssh` access to some other remote servers which are not accessible through `eth1` but `eth0` has the access. So I need to change the route for this requests. My first solution was this:

```
route add -net 10.20.33.0/24 gw 172.17.42.1
```

This approach works fine and I'll get access to those addresses in range `10.20.33.0/24`. But it will block access from those hosts to application itself. The application is serving on port 80 and after adding this route, all requests to it from hosts in range `10.20.33.0/24` will fail.

So I suppose that route is so global and effects all input/output requests to that range of IPs. I searched for a way to just route output ssh requests all over stackoverflow and so far this is what I have:

```
# Initialize route table
echo 1 p.ssh > /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add table p.ssh default via 172.17.42.1

# Mark Packet with matching D.Port
iptables -A PREROUTING  -t mangle -p tcp --dport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j SNAT --to 172.17.42.1


#IP Route
ip rule add fwmark 1 table p.ssh
ip route flush cache

#IP Stack
#This is the missing part from the guide
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
for f in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter ; do echo 0 > $f ; done
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush
```

But it is not working. I've tried to log the marked package by `iptables` so maybe I could find any issue in the process but the `syslog` is not running inside the container, so I installed it `apt-get install rsyslog` and added this rule:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING  -t mangle -p tcp --dport 22 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "fwmark 1: "
```

But it's not logging anything either.

Comment: have you removed this route: route add -net 10.20.33.0/24 gw 172.17.42.1 after you have set iptables for route ssh only ?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/multigateway-routing-for-specific-src-port?rq=1 might help to solve your issues.

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Yes, I've removed that route, and thanks about the link, I've tried it (The last comment in response) and nothing changed, the problem still remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a couple of days I was able to solve this problem. I used `tcpdump` as follow to find out if the traffic is routing through `eth0` interface or not:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 port ssh
```

And it turned out that the first problem is from `iptables` marking command. So instead of marking requests on `PREROUTING` chain, I marked them on `OUTPUT` chain like follow:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

Now I was able to see the ssh requests on `eth0` but still I couldn't connect. It turned out that this requests need to be masqueraded to function properly:

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j MASQUERADE
```

The final script is now like:

```
REMOTE_HOSTS=10.20.33.0/24
HOSTS_ADDR=172.17.42.1

# Add table
echo 1 p.ssh >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
# Add route
ip rule add fwmark 1 table p.ssh
ip route add $REMOTE_HOSTS via $HOSTS_ADDR dev eth0 table p.ssh

# Sets mark correctly
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j MASQUERADE

#IP Stack
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward     # Default in debian/ubuntu
for f in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter ; do echo 0 > $f ; done
```